# In Android getting from a Byte map returns Integers

Tags: java, android, apache-commons

The line is:

`BidiMap<Byte, Character> map = new BidiMap<>();`

`System.out.println((Byte) map.getKey('?'));`

The IDE marks the Byte cast as redundant (it should) because map.getKey(Character) should always return a Byte. Yet, when the line runs I get:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte`

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Edit:

The insertion code:

```
Byte b = 0b00000000;

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mainActivity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text_encoding)));

String line;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
     map.put(b++, line.charAt(0));
}
```

The text file is just a list of characters that I want to be associated with a byte encoding.

Comment: try writing Character.valueOf('?') as getKey argument, I don't have experience with BidiMap but I hope you have created a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: It is 1:1 and I tried your suggestion and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Where do you insert into the map?

Comment: What's wrong with `println(map.getKey('?'))` or `println(Byte.toString(map.getKey('?')))`?

Comment: I'm not actually interested in the string, I'm interested in the byte result of map.ketkey('?"). The println was just a way of testing it.

Comment: @Joni I put it in the edit.